# Form no muestra info en tabla - logica de js

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una duda respecto a un formulario que recibe información en mi archivo html y luego envía como parámetros la info de los inputs del formulario, a una función que tengo en mi archivo de javascript...

Debe de ser muy sencilla la respuesta sin embargo me gustaría que alguien me explique para entender mejor la lógica de la programación.

Tengo los siguientes archivos:

index.html

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <form onsubmit=" return agregarMeta(this)" class="myDiv">
                <label for="hijosselect">Selecciona tu Hijo:</label>
                <br>
                <select name="hijosselect">
                    <option value="default" selected disabled> </option>
                    <option value="david">David</option>
                    <option value="rodrigo">Rodrigo</option>
                    <option value="fernando">Fernando</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>  
                <label for="titulo">Titulo:</label><br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Titulo" name="titulo">
                <br><br>
                <label for="meta">Meta / Objetivo:</label><br>
                <textarea placeholder="Mensaje" name="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar">
                <input type="button" value="Ver Lista" onclick="console.log(metas)">
                <br><br>
            </form>  
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="column" >
            <table id="tabla" >
                <tr>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Hijo</th>
                    <th>Meta / Objetivo</th>
                    <th>Acción</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button onclick="eliminar()">Eliminar</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> 
    </div>       
   
    
</body>
```

main.js

```
const nuevaInfo = ( ) =>
`
    <table id="tabla">
        <tr>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Hijo</th>
            <th>Meta / Objetivo</th>
            <th>Acción</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>${metas.titulo}</td>
            <td>Fernando</td>
            <td>${metas.mensaje}</td>
            <td><button onclick="eliminar()">Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    `

   const func = setTimeout(function(){ nuevaInfo() }, 10000);


var metas = {}

function agregarMeta(form){
    metas[form.hijosselect.value] = {titulo: form.titulo.value, mensaje: form.mensaje.value}
    return false

}    

window.onload =  () => {
    const data =   document.getElementById('tabla')
    data.innerHTML = func    

}
```

Mi duda esta en que si yo corro asi tal cual el script, **mi tabla se convierte en un cuadrito con un #1 adentro.**

Pero si yo directamente en el window.onload al data.innerHTML (en lugar de meterlo en la variable "func")le doy el valor de : nuevaInfo() la tabla si se ve...

```
window.onload =  () => {
    const data =   document.getElementById('tabla')
    data.innerHTML = nuevaInfo()    

}
```

**Mi duda es, por que me sale el 1 adentro del cuadro en lugar de la tabla como tal...**

Estoy haciendo este experimento para entender la logica. Yo se que como el nuevo objeto se esta guardando en el navegador en la tabla sale los valores de "undefined" pero no se supone que si yo hago click en el submit del formulario antes de los primeros 10 segundos por el setTimeOut() en la tabla debería de salir la información (solo en ese intervalo de 10 sec)?

Answer (score 0):

El objetivo lo resolví de esta manera. Sin embargo si alguien me pudiera explicar el por que mi logica estaba mal en la primer pregunta, se lo agradeceria mucho!

index.html

```
 <form onsubmit="return agregarMeta(this)" class="myDiv">
                <label for="hijosselect">Selecciona tu Hijo:</label>
                <br>
                <select name="hijosselect">
                    <option value="default" selected disabled> </option>
                    <option value="David">David</option>
                    <option value="Rodrigo">Rodrigo</option>
                    <option value="Fernando">Fernando</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>  
                <label for="titulo">Titulo:</label><br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Titulo" name="titulo">
                <br><br>
                <label for="meta">Meta / Objetivo:</label><br>
                <textarea placeholder="Mensaje" name="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar">
                <input type="button" value="Ver Lista" onclick="console.log(metas)">
                <br><br>
            </form>
```

main.js

```
const nuevaInfo = (metas) =>
`
    <table id="tabla">
        <tr>
            <th>Hijo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Meta / Objetivo</th>
            <th>Acción</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>${metas.hijosselect}</td>
            <td>${metas.titulo}</td>
            <td>${metas.mensaje}</td>
            <td><button onclick="eliminar()">Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    `
    

var metas = {} 


function agregarMeta(form){
    metas = {hijosselect: form.hijosselect.value, titulo: form.titulo.value, mensaje: form.mensaje.value}
    recibeMuestra(metas)
    return false

}   

function recibeMuestra(metas){
    const data = document.getElementById('tabla') 
    data.innerHTML = nuevaInfo(metas)
}
```